# RSA: How to split char * table into chunks for encryption?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am writing my own RSA implementation. I found it difficult to find correct way of selecting size of chunk of data to be encrypted. I already have proper keys generation implemented, the only thing that's left is encryption ( well, it is implemented but it won't work properly ).

Here is my code:

```
template
    <
        typename NumberType,
        typename EncryptionResultType,
        typename DecryptionResultType,
        typename DataProvider,
        typename RandomNumberProvider
    >
EncryptionResultType RSAAlgorithm
                    <
                        NumberType,
                        EncryptionResultType,
                        DecryptionResultType,
                        DataProvider,
                        RandomNumberProvider
                    >

::Encrypt(DataProvider * provider)

{

    char * data = provider->ProvideData();
    long size = strlen(data);

    size_t chunkSize = sizeof(NumberType);

    char * result = new char[size];

    for(NumberType i=0;i < size;i+=chunkSize)
    {

        NumberType dataChunkAsNumber = 0;
        memcpy(&dataChunkAsNumber,data+i,chunkSize);
        NumberType value = ModularPower<NumberType>(dataChunkAsNumber, publicKey, modulus);
        memcpy(result+i,&value,chunkSize);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any necessary static checks (about implicit conversions, correctness of interface of DataProvider type etc ) would be implemented, but that's not the point :)
The point is - given NumberType (which can be long , or some BigNumber library) and having publicKey of type NumberType, how can i calculate , or just tell the best / most efficient for algorithm  size of chunk of data to be encrypted?

I made this attempt. 
In my unerstanding - we take a chunk of text that can be held in NumberType and use it binary representation to create NumberType with same binary representation (let's call it Mi), using memcpy. We encrypt it using modular power -> we get another NumberType (lets call it Ci),which after being decrypted should give us Mi back. When we take the binary representation of result and memcpy it to char * we should get the text back. But it won't work . 
Anybody know's what am i doing / understanding wrong ?

Edit:: For test i used char * which size was multiplication of sizeof(NumberType)

Answer (score 3):

### RSA output size

The RSA encryption formula in short is this: `m^e mod n`, which encrypts the message `m` with `0 <= m < n` using the public key `(e,n)` with `n=p*q` for two primes `p`,`q` <sup>†</sup>. To achieve reasonable security `n` typically has a size of 2048 bits (i.e. `2^2047 < n < 2^2048`) to 8192 bits (i.e. `2^8191 < n < 2^8192`). Thus the result `m^e mod n` has a bit size of 2048 bits = 256 bytes or more. And for decryption (`c^d mod n`<sup>‡</sup>) you need the full output of `m^e mod n`. You can't cut it down to just one byte. So a naive way to solve your issue is to just blow up the output size.

### Basic efficiency

`pow(data[i], publicKey)` will create a huge intermediate result. If `e` is not tiny, it will be larger than your main memory. Instead, [fast modular exponentiation methods to a modular operation after each multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method). There is a `pow` function available with three parameters (base, exponent, modulus) in most languages and BigNum libraries.

### Security considerations

Encrypting each byte separately is a bad idea, though. Consider this attack: For each possible byte `0 <= j < 256` calculate the ciphertext `c`<sub>`j`</sub>`= j^e mod n`. Now you have a lookup table to reverse encryption.

**In general RSA is not fit to encrypt data directly**, because its deterministic encryption means you can always test values against the given ciphertext, there are certain other undesirable algebraic properties and RSA itself is hideously slow. Instead RSA is usually used in a **hybrid encryption scheme** where only a symmetric key for AES (or Salsa20, etc.) is exchanged<sup>¶</sup> via RSA and the use data is encrypted symmetrically.

The easiest method to exchange the symmetric key I have found so far is described in [Cryptography Enginnering](https://www.schneier.com/book-ce.html). *Encryption*:

- Let `b` be the bit length of `n`. Usually that means `b>=2048`.
- Choose `m` as a random number in the interval `0,1,2,...,2^(b-1)-1`. This is more convenient than choosing it in the interval `0,1,2,n-1` as you can just sample `b` random bits, set the highest valued bit to zero and interpret the result as the BigNum `m`.
- Encrypt `m` using RSA (let the result be `c`).
- Hash `m` using a cryptographically secure hash function, e.g. SHA256, to get the symmetric key `k` and encrypt and authenticate<sup>§</sup> your data symmetrically using `k`.
- (Transmit the authenticated and encrypted data along with `c`.)

*Decryption*:

- Decrypt `c` to get back `m`.
- Do **not** check whether `m` is in the interval `0,1,2,...,2^(b-1)-1`. This will introduce an oracle attack to your scheme, ala the [Bleichenbacher attack](http://archiv.infsec.ethz.ch/education/fs08/secsem/Bleichenbacher98.pdf).
- Hash `m` to get the symmetric key `k` and decrypt and authenticate your data symmetrically using `k`.

Implementing cryptography is pretty hard and contains a bunch of hidden pitfalls, so you only want to do it yourself to learn the concepts. **Don't ever use your own implementations in production code.** Instead, use high level libraries like [Sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) to make your life easier and safer.

#### Footnotes:

<sup>†</sup> And `0 < e < phi(n)=(p-1)*(q-1)` and `gcd(e,phi(n)=1`, but that is not all too important for this question.

<sup>‡</sup> Where `c=m^e mod n` is the ciphertext and `0 < d < phi(n)` with `e*d ≡ 1 mod phi(n)`.

<sup>§</sup> Authentication is an important step of every cryptographic protocol. Explaining why goes beyond the scope of this answer. The GCM block cipher mode is a good authenticated encryption scheme, that encrypts and authenticates in parallel.

<sup>¶</sup> Please note that the symmetric key is not encrypted directly. Here we derive it from a random value that is chosen from a large subset of the numbers `0,1,2,...,n-1`. See the explanation further on in the answer. A more commonly used alternative is to embedded a key using [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding). I discourage OAEPs use for new protocols, though, because of it's [high susceptibility to side channel attacks](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2001/21390229.pdf).

Comment: @owlstead: Re 1: I did not say that RSA cannot be secure without hybrid encryption, but only that it is not fit to encrypt data "directly". Combined with the following sentence I see how you got that impression, though, so I have added the qualifier "usually" to make it more clear. Re 2: If I recall correctly, the security reduction of OAEP relies on the fact that it is not possible to calculate the `e`th root for a random element in `F_n`. The key derivation scheme I propose (or rather have copied from Cryptography Engineering) for this answer uses this assumption far more directly.

Comment: @owlstead: I dare say it is more tight than OAEP, as it only reduces the space of numbers the random value `m` is chosen from by a factor less than two and does not require a random oracle assumption needed for the mask generation function. Instead it requires that the hash function does not reduce the entropy significantly below 256bit and a secure authenticated encryption scheme. The new footnote ¶ (added in the edit) also explains that I dislike OAEP, as it leaves significant room for implementation errors and in general is more complex, than the scheme proposed above.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have the time to respond, I already have upvoted this. The chance that `m` is too short is clearly insignificant, and I don't see any immediate drawbacks to the scheme.